# Deployment of C# project with C++ redistributable for DLL:s

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, vcredist

I'm creating a Setup.msi installer for my C# application to be deployed on other machines.

My application is deployed with some C++ DLL:s and this would require Visual++ runtime libraries (vcredist_x86.exe or vcredist_x64.exe) to be installed first.

So I'm trying to solve this issue by generating one Setup_x64.msi which has the following merge modules:

```
Microsoft_VC100_CRT_x64.msm
Microsoft_VC100_MFC_x64.msm
Microsoft_VC100_OpenMP_x64.msm
```

These are simply added via right click->Add->Merge Module... as follows:

[image: Adding VC100 modules]

Is this the correct way to go about taking care of this dependency? I dont want the end-users to have to manually install any vcredist...exe , and since I'm currently all out of failing deployment machines I'm trying to verify that this is the correct approach?

Thank you so much for yout time!

//Jimmy

Comment: Well, sure.  But just don't, nothing that pretty about your install failing because somebody else got to c:\windows with a newer version before you did.  It used to be important when the CRT had to be installed in the side-by-side cache but those days are over, starting with VS2010.  Just copy the DLLs into the same directory as your EXE.

Comment: @HansPassant This isn't the `MSVCRT.DLL` he's talking about. This will be installing `MSVCR100.DLL` and the merge module is the correct way to do this. See what [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/04/11/10516280.aspx) has to say.

Comment: Yes, I know.  That merge module will copy msvcr100.dll to c:\windows\system32 or syswow64.  DLL Hell is back.

Comment: @Hans Passant, so you're caliming that if someone already has installed a runtime my installation would fail? Would It have to be like a VS2012 runtime etc?

Comment: No, a VS2010 version.  There is more than one, at least RTM, SP1 and a security update.

Comment: Ah, so if someone already has for example VS2012 installed that would cause a failure during the installarion process?